# How to make a config.yaml and write to it with the help of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yaml

The title pretty much says it all. I just want to save data and access it anytime I want. JS-Yaml is very good for parsing yaml but the thing is that I also need to know how to make a config and write data to that yaml + get that data. Thanks

Comment: I just want to have something like a database where I will store each user's details f.e id, password, items, etc. And I want to do it with yaml, so yeah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using node js, there are plenty of libraries available to read and write yaml file

You can try using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-yaml

> npm install --save node-yaml

It has functions for open, parse and write yml files. Also I like the documentation